# I just killed the wrong machine on openshift

Tags: openshift

I am free user in Openshift. There are 3 machine available. 
I used 1 to write my blog.

About 1 hr ago. I just want to delete another machine, so I click button "delete".
And than, I found that I delete the wrong one.
So my blog is killed by me....

How can I receive my data ??
My blog is blog-whycat.rhcloud.com

Comment: As long there is no relation to programming try http://superuser.com however in your case I hope you have done backups, use them. I'm sure the data in the cloud are gone forever.

Comment: Just because you delete an app doesn't remove the local copy on your machine.  You should still have all the code at the location you cloned the repo at app creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me quote the delete confirmation page:

> This will delete all the code and data associated with the app, and
>   **cannot be undone**.

If you really don't have any backups, your best bet would be to [contact the support](https://www.openshift.com/support).